# Can affine transformation make two intersective lines become parallel?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

The book *Geometry of Conics*, by Akopyan and Zaslavsky, states a problem as follows:

> **Probelem 9** A line intersects a hyperbola at points $P$ and $Q$ and
> its asymptotes at points $X$ and $Y$. Prove that the segments $PX$ and
> $QY$ are equal.

Besides, it gives a proof as follows:

> Apply an **affine transformation** such that the line becomes parallel to one of the axes of the hyperbola. Then the desired equality would follow from symmetry. But since the segments in question lie on a line, their images under the affine transformation will also be equal.

It's well-known that the affine transformation preserves the parallelism, in another word, under such transformation, parallel lines are also parallel, and intersective lines are still intersective. How can an affine transformation make the line and the axis (not always parallel) become parallel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is about

> **Problem 9** A line intersects a hyperbola at points $P$ and $Q$ and
> its asymptotes at points $X$ and $Y$. Prove that the segments $PX$ and
> $QY$ are equal.

The proof given requires an affine transformation such that the line
becomes parallel to one of the axes of the hyperbola. However, as noted
in the question, if the line is not parallel to one of the axes of
symmetry of the hyperbola and intersects them both, then no affine
transformation can make it parallel to one of the axes of the transformed
hyperbola because the intersection points are also transformed.

Despite this, the result is true because the given proof is valid when
it is interpreted properly. If the given line does intersect at least
one of the axes of the hyperbola, then apply an affine transformation that
fixes the asymptotes and makes the distance of $X$ and $Y$ from the other axis equal. In this case, the given line now becomes parallel to the other
axis of the transformed hyperbola. Note the **transformed** axes of the
original hyperbola need **not** be the same as the new axes of the transformed hyperbola, so there is no problem about parallel lines.

Compare this to the case of the center of a circle under inversion in a
given circle where the inverted circle center is not the inverse of the
center of the original circle unless this circle maps to itself.

The proof states

> Then the desired equality would follow from symmetry.

which is easy to show and the proof is complete.

Perhaps an example will makes this clearer. Draw the hyperbola graph of $y=1/x$. Draw the line $y=x/2+1$ through the points $Y=(-2,0), X=(0,1), (2,2), (-4,1)$. Draw the symmetry axes $y=x$ and $y=-x$. Use the affine
transformation $(x,y)\mapsto(x,2y)$. The new graph is the hyperbola $y=2/x$. The line is now $y=x+2$ which is parallel to the symmetry axis $y=x$ which is the same as the old one.

A proof using analytic geometry could be given. Let $a,b$ be nonzero
numbers. Without loss of generality let the hyperbola be $y=1/x.$ Define

$$ d=\sqrt{c^2-4ab},\quad e=(c-d)/2,\quad f=(c+d)/2 $$

and points

$$ X=(0,c/b),\; Y=(c/a, 0),\; P = (e/a, f/b),\; Q = (f/a, e/b).$$

Verify that

$$ ef = ab,\; cP = fX+eY,\; cQ = eX+fY,\; P\!-\!X = Y\!-\!Q $$

to complete the proof.

Comment: So in other words, the axes of a hyperbola are not an affine invariant? That makes sense; the axes of the hyperbola are the angle bisectors of the angles made by the asymptotes, and being an angle bisector is not preserved by affine transformations.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Exactly! Some properties and geometric relations are not affine invariant. That is the case for the two symmetry axes which are orthogonal to each other but angles are not always affine invariant.

Comment: Sir,I have not understood you yet. Can you make it more clearly, or give an illustration?

Comment: @mengdie1982 Thanks for that comment! I have added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I get it perfectly. The point is that, the axes are not always the axes under affine transformation.

Answer (score 1):

It can make intersecting lines perpendicular.  For take $M$ the middle of segment $XY$, $O$ the intersection of the asymptotes. In affine geometry we do not have angles, so we cannot say  $OM \perp XY$.  However, (assume the base field $\mathbb{R}$)  we can choose a metric  such that $OM \perp XY$. Then $OM$ is also an axis of symmetry of the pair of asymptotes.  Therefore it is an axis of symmetry of the hyperbola, etc.

Notes:

1. In fact, we can make both $XY\perp OM$ and also the asymptotes perpendicular.
2. Perhaps one should prove that $\frac{M+N}{2}=\frac{X+Y}{2}$. This does not require the notion of length,  and the field can be arbitrary, of characteristic not $2$. If that is to be allowed, then  $Y-M = N-X$ would do.